# R: Building a list from matching values in a data.frame

Tags: r, list, extract, dataframe

I have a 3 column data frame which looks a little like this:

```
    id      name    links
1   134235  dave    "34657","34563","23459" 
2   23459   mary    "134235","45868","45677"
3   165432  jane    "134235","23459","44657"
```

where id and name values are unique, and links is a string of ids which indicate an association with some of the names in each row. So for example dave includes the links id 23459 which is mary so dave is connected to mary. What I need to produce is a pair list of all the connections in the data so with the example data I would output something like:

```
dave,mary
mary,dave
jane,dave
jane,mary
```

Very new to R and seen amazing things done with methods like `apply` and before going off and trying to replicate a solution which would look more like a javascript routine and be very inefficient I wondered if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution, using Matt's dput():

```
tab <- structure(list(
  id = c("134235", "23459", "165432"),
  name = c("dave", "mary", "jane"),
  links = c("'34657', '34563', '23459'",
            "'134235', '45868', '45677'", 
            "'134235', '23459', '44657'")),
  .Names = c("id", "name", "links"),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

conns <- function(name, links) {
  paste(name, tab$name[tab$id %in% as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('\'|\"',
    '', links), ',')))], sep=',')
}

connections <- unname(unlist(mapply(conns, tab$name, tab$links, 
  SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
```

Comment: <stunned silence ... then/> this is awesome! I knew R was powerful, but this puts it in another league. So I can learn from this mapply is going to run the function conns on each row of tab doing something with name and links (what is returned from this is unlisted and unnamed). Within conns for each 'links' you split and see if each id is in it. If it is this match is used to return the name.

Comment: mhawksey, impressive use of all the two letter words beginning with 'i' in a single clause (ok, you're using the variable 'id', but it's one of the closest examples I've found using a google search).

Answer (score 0):

```
dat<- structure(list(
    id = c("134235", "23459", "165432"),
    name = c("dave", "mary", "jane"),
    links = c("'34657', '34563', '23459'",
              "'134235', '45868', '45677'", 
              "'134235', '23459', '44657'")),
    .Names = c("id", "name", "links"),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")


# It can all be done in base, of course...
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)

# This would be easy to do if links weren't in that format - 
# one record per id-link pair would be preferable.
# Split dat$links and remove any quotes
dat.wider <- data.frame(
    dat[ , c("id", "name")],
    str_split_fixed(string = gsub(dat$links, 
                                  pattern = "['|\"]", 
                                  replace = ""),
                    pattern = ", ", 
                    n = 3)
)

# Reshape
dat.long <- melt(dat.wider, id.var = c("id", "name"))

# Self-join - this is not quite the right method, but I'm just not
# thinking straight right now
dat.joined <- unique(merge(x = dat.long[ , c("name", "value")],
                           y = dat.long[ , c("id", "name")],
                           by.x = "value",
                           by.y = "id"
))

# And, finally, if you wanted vector output...
res <- with(dat.joined, paste(name.x, name.y, sep = ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be to normalize the data, in particular, parse the strings.
You can use `ddply`: it applies a function 
that takes a chunk of a data.frame (a row, in our case)
and transforms it in some way. You just have to write a function 
that works on one row, i.e., on one string.

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
k <- 3
ids <- as.character(unique(round(1e5*runif(n))))
n <- length(ids)
names <- LETTERS[1:n]
links <- lapply( ids, function(u) 
  sample(setdiff(ids,u),k,replace=FALSE) )
links <- sapply( links, function(u) 
  paste( '"', paste(u,collapse='","'), '"', sep="" ) )
d <- data.frame( 
  id=ids, 
  name=names, 
  links=links, 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE 
)

library(plyr)
library(stringr)
dd <- ddply( 
  d, 
  c("id", "name"), 
  function(u) data.frame(
    id=u$id, 
    name=u$name, 
    link=unlist(str_split( str_replace_all( u$links, '"', '' ), "," ))
))
```

You can then join the data, either with `merge` or `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf(" 
  SELECT A.name, B.name 
  FROM dd AS A, d AS B 
  WHERE A.link = B.id 
")
```